# Flash doesn't show any message

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a `_flash` subtemplate:

```
@(flash: Flash)

@flash.data.foreach { x =>
    @x._1, @x._2
}
```

This code never shows any flash message. The code below doesn't work either

```
@if(!flash.isEmpty) {
    @for((msgKey, msgValue) <- flash) { 
        <div class="alert alert-@msgKey" data-dismiss="alert">      
            <a title="@Messages("misc.message.close")" class="close">×</a>
            @msgKey
        </div>
    }
}
```

due to the error at runtime: `filter is not a member of Flash`. And oddly enough, the code below does work and show a message:

```
@flash.get("success")
```

How I set the message is not important because it works well in the last case, however, there is the code for it:

```
if (success) {
  Redirect(routes.Application.success).flashing("success" -> "Ok123")
} else {
    Ok(views.html.registration.add(newForm))
}
```

My aim is loop over flash because it want to show all messages in `_flash` subtemplate.

**UPDATE**: I realized why the first approach doesn't work (I have to use map instead). But why does the second one raise the error at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error, you missed flash.**data**. From [Play 2.0 API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Flash.htm) we see that Flash is a

`case class Flash (data: Map[String, String]) extends Product with Serializable`

So the correct code should be:

```
@if(!flash.isEmpty) {
    @for((msgKey, msgValue) <- flash.data) { 
        <div class="alert alert-@msgKey" data-dismiss="alert">      
            <a title="@Messages("misc.message.close")" class="close">×</a>
            @msgKey
        </div>
    }
}
```

I'm almost sure that this is compile-time error, you see it in runtime only because you use dev mode.
BTW, I usually do something like this:

```
@()(implicit flash: play.api.mvc.Flash)

 @flash.get("success").map { message =>  
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             @message
        </div>
    }

    @flash.get("failure").map { message =>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
           <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a> 
             @message
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: About your approach: what if there are more than 2 message types?

Comment: Your approach is totally fine if you have a lot of message types. But if you have, say, ten of them why bother with iterator, you've already refactored display logic into a single file so I think it is acceptable to just list this types in the template.